# Having trouble setting constraints of 2 views one on top and one on bottom in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm currently trying to have 2 views on top of each other in a CustomCell.

The issue i'm running into is only the top view gets displayed.

Debugging the view it shows that the height for the top view is ambiguous and for the bottom view the height and vertical position is ambiguous.

I'm currently setting the height for these custom cells using the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` method and setting it to `UITableView.automaticDimension` and setting the cosntraints using the code below inside the CustomCells `layoutSubviews` method.

What am I missing?

Thank you

What the tableView with the customCells currently looks like, it should have a greenView and a blackView under the greenView with a space of 10.

[image]

**CustomTableViewCell**

```swift
/// Adds it to contentView. This get's called in the `init()`
private func setupUI() {
        setupCellContentView()
        self.contentView.addSubview(topContainerView)
        self.contentView.addSubview(bottomContainerView)
    }

override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let topContainerViewViewConstraints = [
            topContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            topContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            topContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        ]
        let bottomContainerViewConstraints = [
            bottomContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            bottomContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            bottomContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            bottomContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10)
        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(topContainerViewViewConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(bottomContainerViewConstraints)
    }

/// Bottom container view is set up the exact same way as topContainerView.
lazy var topContainerView: UIView = {
        let container = UIView()
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        container.backgroundColor = .green
        return container
}()
```

**TableView**

```swift
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
private func setupUI() {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
        self.view.backgroundColor = .none
        self.view.addSubview(contentView)
    }

    private func setupConstraintsForContentView() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
}

extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        viewModel.scoresData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell: ScoresTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "scoresTableViewCell",
                                                                            for: indexPath) as? ScoresTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.setupCellData(with: viewModel.scoresData[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the entire `layoutSubviews` method, and all other code in the cell that has anything at all to do with constraints. In the tiny (and rather useless) snippet of code you've shown us so far, you do not have _any_ constraints; you _made_ some, but you didn't _activate_ any. We cannot help if you do not show us your _real code._

Comment: @matt They were activated just didn't include it in the code. It's edited to show the whole method now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not assigned any constraints to either container view that would give either of them any height. The width is unambiguous because the views are pinned to the left and right of the content view, whose width is in turn determined by the table view itself; but the height of the content view is the unknown that the runtime is trying to determine, and you are not giving it any help.

When the top container view is given a height, its height will no longer be ambiguous and its bottom will therefore be known, and in turn the top of the bottom container view will no longer be ambiguous. When the bottom container view is given a height, there will be no further ambiguity and the content view (and hence the cell) will adopt a correct height.

So the information you have gathered from the debugger is correct. The only surprise as far as I'm concerned is that you can see any cell at all!

Comment: Okay I understand that.

But if i wanted to add a label inside one of these containers and it's dynamic, if I set a fixed height wouldn't cause certain cases to make the text not visible? I want to avoid putting a fixed value for height and rather use constraints. Would that be possible?

Comment: That's right, but you did _not_ add a label. A hypothetical does you no good here; just like me, the runtime layout engine can only deal with what you give it. You didn't give it any label so there's no point talking about that.

Comment: Shouldn't it be able to calculate the height of the container based on the constraints I provided? I just want to avoid hard coding a `height` value for the container and just use autoLayout.

Comment: So you're correct defining a physical value for a height makes everything work fine. So it's impossible to do this just with constraining the 2 views inside the cell?

Comment: Thank you. You were correct.

I was able to prevent adding a manual height, by creating containers, adding the labels inside the container, adding the containers to the view and then constraining them. The issue was I was trying to add views into the container and add the container to the view all in one. There needs to be some view inside the label in order to determine a height and then you can add those to your custom cell. Thank you!

Comment: "Shouldn't it be able to calculate the height of the container based on the constraints I provided" Just to be clear: No. That's what my answer tells you.